# best HTML and CSS markup practices for websites where mobile design is different

Tags: html, css

So I'm requesting a solution to markup practices. I am working on an administrator back end design, now I am looking to not necessarily work with responsive design but have completely different behaviour.

Would it be better to use an entirely different site?

Should I include both desktop and mobile HTML and hide/show accordingly with media queries?

What is generally the best way to setup for this and what method to approach as I need the designs to be different in terms of HTML and CSS but I want to have good standards of practice.

Comment: I think it really depends on whether you want to maintain two separate, yet similar websites.

Comment: I would rather 1 is it bad to have HTML elements for both desktop and mobile and manage it with media queries ?

Comment: One option would be to use the user agent on the server side to render either desktop OR mobile elements, keeping as much common ground as possible. I'd be hesitant to use media queries *if* it will result in you loading a lot of unnecessary DOM content into the mobile browser.

Comment: i think it's great to have 2 sites with clean structure, unique design, speed, and  less tangled code.

Comment: the one size that fits all doesn't truly fits anyone...unless you want your site to look like another mutation of bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you are looking for the best mobile optimization methods. There are a number of solutions to this problem. Peronally, most of what I design isn't meant to be used on mobile devices because of the nature of it, but I try and follow these habits:

1:Use percentages/ems for measurements (height, width, margin). These are adjustable, and will render at least decently on a mobile device. Build a website using only px measurements, and you're screwed.
2:make sure your code is compatible with chrome, firefox, and safari. these are the most common mobile browsers.

ALSO

Having separate sites is acceptable, but i wouldn't recommend it, because any updates you do to one site, you have to do to the other, which could get tedious.  As I understand it, it would be better to use media queries(from what I know, there are multiple CSS and/or javascript libraries/frameworks for this) and based on whether it's a mobile device, apply different stylings.

Answer (score 1):

It might be just me but if you're going to write a website, do it properly **ONCE**. There's a fundamental programming rule *Don't Repeat Yourself* (DRY) which I like to live by. The best way to achieve this is using media queries and percentage values. Media queries allow you to have completely different styles based on device size and moving forward with web design, something definitely worth investing your time in.